# Error: input string was not in a correct format

Tags: asp.net

I create stored procedure in the following format.

```
ALTER procedure [spInsertEmp]
@empName varchar(50),
@Emp_Id int ,
@option varchar(10)
as
set nocount off


IF  @option='delete'

delete from emp where Emp_Id=@Emp_Id   

if @option='insert'

IF EXISTS(select EmpName from emp where EmpName=@empName)
return -1
ELSE
insert into emp (EmpName)values(@empName) 

if @option='update'
begin
   UPDATE emp set Empname=@empname where Emp_Id=@Emp_Id
End
```

in that I gave codebehind using c# like below format

```
    protected void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server = MYLAPTOP;uid=sa;pwd =hari_123; database =test1");

        //conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsertEmp", conn);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@empName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtAdditionalChargeType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Emp_Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value =Convert.ToInt32(txtAdditionalChargeType1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@option", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "update";
```

in that I got error for this line

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Emp_Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value =Convert.ToInt32(txtAdditionalChargeType1.Text);
```

The error was

> input string was not in a correct format

So any one help me to give the update button code belongs this above stored procedure. Please help me.

Comment: you can't convert string to int if the string contains alphabhets , if it contains numerics then its ok.

Comment: this post should not be tagged with Silverlight. it better go with SQL StoredProcedre and .net

Answer (score 0):

This will occur if your input string could not be converted to an integer (for example, "123" can be converted, but "123abc" obviously can't). You can use TryParse instead:

```
int additionalChargeType1;
if(int.TryParse(txtAdditionalChargeType1.Text, out additionalChargeType))
{
    //The conversion works, now do something with additionalChargeType
}
else
{
    //The conversion didn't work.
}
```